# Different iterators are giving me different answers

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between

```
for i in range(0,3): print cons[i]['fun'](x0)
```

and

```
for f in cons: print f['fun'](x0)
```

where cons is defined as following

```
A = np.asmatrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
x0 = np.asarray([1,2,0])
cons = list()
for i in range(0,3): cons.append({'fun':lambda x: np.dot(A[i],x)})
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem probably is related to the fact that you are having a lambda clause using an unbound variable (`i`).  Change your code like this:

```
for i in range(0,3): cons.append({'fun':lambda x, i=i: np.dot(A[i],x)})
```

(I. e. just insert that `, i=i`.)

This way the value of `i` is part of the lambda clause and not taken from the surrounding scope.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it.

So if I understand this correctly, every time that 'i' increments it updates 'A[i]' for the previous entry in the list as well?

Comment: Accepting would be nice, but there's an open question; here my response:  Yes.  All the lambdas you create are dependent from a variable named `i` which they don't hold themselves.  The value of `i` in the surrounding scope determines the outcome at evaluation time.  If at this time there is no `i` in the surrounding scope, you'll get an exception.

Comment: Not the surrounding scope, but the *enclosing* scope. The original `i` from the loop used to populate `cons`, is the variable that will be used for the closure. After that loop has run, it has the value `2`. Given `for i in range(0,3): print cons[i]['fun'](x0)`, it will change - because the same `i` from the same scope is being reassigned. `for f in cons: print f['fun'](x0)` on the other hand will keep using the `2` value.